# Radial and pseudoradial properties for Tychonoff plank and variants

Tags: general-topology

The *Tychonoff plank* is the product $(\omega_1+1)\times(\omega+1)=[0,\omega_1]\times[0,\omega]$ where each factor has the order topology.  The *deleted Tychonoff plank* is the Tychonoff plank with the point $(\omega_1,\omega)$ removed.  I am wondering about the radial and pseudoradial properties for these spaces.

A space $X$ is called [pseudoradial](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000173) if every radially closed set is closed.  Equivalently, for every non-closed set $A\subseteq X$ there is a point $p\in\overline A\setminus A$ and a transfinite sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ with each $x_\alpha\in A$ and converging to $p$.  (Here $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and can always be taken to be a regular cardinal.)

A space $X$ is called [radial](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000172) if for every non-closed set $A\subseteq X$ and every point $p\in\overline A\setminus A$ there is a transfinite sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ with each $x_\alpha\in A$ and converging to $p$.

For the Tychonoff plank, the results below are stated in the article by [Horst Herrlich (1967)](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-61-1-79-81) that introduced the pseudoradial and radial properties, but without justification.

- The Tychonoff plank is not radial.  I give a proof below.
- The Tychonoff plank is pseudoradial.
- The deleted Tychonoff plank is radial.  I give a proof below.
- The deleted Tychonoff plank is pseudoradial (because radial implies pseudoradial).

> How to prove the Tychonoff plank is pseudoradial?

Would also appreciate if you could check the validity of my proofs below.

---

**Proof that the Tychonoff plank is not radial:**

Let $X=[0,\omega_1]\times[0,\omega]$ be the Tychonoff plank.  Take $A=\omega_1\times\omega$ and $p=(\omega_1,\omega)$.  The point $p$ is in the closure of $A$.  Suppose by contradiction that there is a (transfinite) sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ of points of $A$ converging to $p$.  Taking a cofinal subsequence as necessary, we can assume $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal. Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the projections onto the first and second component.  The sequence $(\pi_1(x_\alpha))_{\alpha<\lambda}$ is a sequence in $\omega_1$ that converges to $\omega_1$.  So necessarily $\lambda\ge\operatorname{cof}(\omega_1)=\omega_1$; in particular $\lambda$ is uncountable.

On the other hand, by considering a suitable nbhd of $p$ we see that for each $n\in\omega$ the $x_\alpha$ are eventually in $\omega_1\times[n+1,\omega)$.  So the cardinality of $\{\alpha<\lambda:\pi_2(x_\alpha)\le n\}$ is less than $\lambda$.  But every $\alpha$ is in one of these sets, so $\lambda$ can be expressed as a countable union of sets, each of cardinality less than $\lambda$, which is not possible as $\lambda$ is a uncountable regular cardinal.

**Observation**:

Since the radial property is hereditary, it follows that the product of larger ordinals is not radial either.  For example $(\omega_1+1)\times(\omega_1+1)$ is not radial.  Is it pseudoradial?

---

**Proof that the deleted Tychonoff plank is radial:**

Let $X=([0,\omega_1]\times[0,\omega])\setminus\{(\omega_1,\omega)\}$ be the deleted Tychonoff plank.  Suppose $A\subseteq X$ is not closed and $p=(p_1,p_2)\in\overline A\setminus A$.

If $p_1<\omega_1$, the nbhd $V=[0,p_1]\times[0,p_2]$ of p is compact Hausdorff and countable, hence metrizable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705764) for example).  As $p$ is in the closure of $V\cap A$, there is a sequence of points in $V\cap A$ converging to $p$.

If $p_1=\omega_1$, necessarily $p_2<\omega$ and $V=[0,\omega_1]\times\{p_2\}$ is a nbhd of $p$ homeomorphic to the radial space $\omega_1+1$.  As $p$ is in the closure of $V\cap A$, there is a (transfinite) sequence of points in $V\cap A$ converging to $p$.

---

As an alternative to the the last proof, one can show the slightly stronger fact:

**The deleted Tychonoff plank is well-based:**

A space is called [well-based](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000174) if every point has a nbhd base well-ordered by reverse inclusion; or equivalently, if every point has a nbhd base totally ordered by inclusion. (See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322162.)  Clearly, a well-based space is radial.

The deleted Tychonoff plank is covered by the open sets $[0,\omega_1)\times[0,\omega]$ and $\{n\}\times[0,\omega_1]$ for $n\in\omega$.  The first open set is first countable, hence well-based; the other open sets are homeomorphic to an ordinal space, hence also well-based.  Since being well-based is a local property, the space is well-based.

Comment: Your proofs look good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a equivalent definition for radial is this: for every set $A$ and limit point $p$ of $A$, there exists a transfinite sequence in $A$ converging to $p$.

Note that a equivalent definition for pseudoradial is this: for every radially closed set $A$ and limit point $p$ of $A$, there exists a transfinite sequence in $A$ converging to $p$.

---

Let $H$ be radially closed in the Tychonoff plank $X$. Let $h$ be a limit point of $H$. We will show that there exists a transfinite sequence in $H$ converging to $h$, and thus show $X$ is pseudoradial.

If $h$ belongs to the deleted Tychonoff plank $Y= X\setminus\{\langle\omega_1,\omega\rangle\}$, there is a transfinite sequence in $H$ converging to $h$ since $Y$ is radial.

Otherwise $h=\langle \omega_1,\omega\rangle$. Suppose we could not construct a transfinite sequence in $H$ converging to $h$. Then there exists $\{\omega_1\}\times(n,\omega]$ disjoint from $H$, and $(\alpha,\omega_1]\times\{\omega\}$ disjoint from $H$. Then for each $\langle\omega_1,N\rangle\in\{\omega_1\}\times(n,\omega]$ there is some $\beta_N$ with $(\beta_N,\omega_1]\times\{N\}$ disjoint from $H$, since $H$ is radially closed. Let $\beta=\sup(\{\alpha\}\cup\{\beta_N:N\in(n,\omega)\})$. Then $(\beta,\omega_1]\times(n,\omega]$ is a neighborhood of $h$ disjoint from $H$, a contradiction.

---

The theorem of http://sci-gems.math.bas.bg/jspui/handle/10525/551 alternatively implies that the product of any two successor ordinals is pseudoradial.

Comment: Thanks for the proof that $X$ is not pseudoradial.  In the second paragraph, "$h$ a limit point of $H$".  Was that meant to be "$h\in\overline H$", and you are showing that in fact $h\in H$?

Comment: I've made an edit that may address your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference at the end.  What I was asking is about the words "limit point of a set" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point), which usually means a point such that every nbhd of it contains a point of the set different from the point itself.  Was that what was meant?

Comment: Yes. Though maybe "accumulation"/"cluster" point would have been clearer here to distinguish from transfinite limits.